# How can I apply a WP filter on specific plugin version

Tags: plugins, filters

I have the plugins list in `'wp-admin/plugins.php'` page. For each plugin there is some meta info extracted by WP from each plugin file:

```
 /*
 * Plugin Name: somename
 * Version: 1.2.3 
 */
```

I want to filter the version of a plugin, to show it in the plugins list, but not to modify the plugin file, just filter the version value.

**Update:**

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: aTestPlugin
 * Version: old.version
 * Description: This plugin is just for testing purpose.
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/atestplugin/
 * Author: mario
 * Author URI: http://www.atestplugin.example/
 */

function atestplugin_plugin_row_meta($meta, $file, $data, $status) { 
    // do some filtering ...
    if ( $data['Name'] == 'aTestPlugin' )
        $meta[0] = 'new.version';

    return $meta;
}
add_filter('plugin_row_meta', 'atestplugin_plugin_row_meta', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for the `plugin_row_meta` filter, where you could add a custom filter like this one:

```
add_filter('plugin_row_meta', 'custom_plugin_row_meta', 10, 4 );
function custom_plugin_row_meta($meta, $file, $data, $status) { 
    //
    // do some filtering on the version text of the Akismet plugin
    //
    if( $file === 'akismet/akismet.php' )
        // $meta[0] = "Version 3.14159265359"; // BAD
        $meta[0] = sprintf( '<strong>%s</strong>', $meta[0] ); // BETTER

    return $meta;
}
```

where we target the version text of the *Akismet* plugin as an example.

**Before:**
[image: before]

**After (with bolded version text):**
[image: after]

**ps:** It could be **very confusing to the user** if you are going to modify the displayed version number of a plugin! So I hope you are only making cosmetic changes to it ;-)

Comment: Yes this is what I asked. Thanks. Instead of `if( $file === 'akismet/akismet.php' )` I can also use `if ( $data['Name'] == 'Akismet' )`.

Comment: ok great, you better post the code in the question  ... or adjust it in the comment text as you just did ;-)